# Compare Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, object, compare

why the first code gives output as "true" and second code gives output as "false"?

code 1
...............
 String str1="abc";
      String str2="abc";

```
  if (str1==str2)
      System.out.println("true");
  else
       System.out.println("false");
```

code 2

NOTE : Input to both string will be same value 
....................

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("enter string 1");
 String String1=sc.next();
 System.out.println("enter string 2");
 String String2=sc.next();

 if(String1==String2)
     System.out.println("true");
 else
     System.out.println("false");
```

Comment: This is the *5,423,232th* time this has been asked

Comment: Stack Overflow should implement a search...

Answer (score 0):

The operator `==` checks the object identity
The `.equals()` method checks if the value is equal to another string's value
use:

```
if (str1.equals(str2)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: does my first code equals to ' .equals() ' ?